# Problems running mocha on Firebase functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, mocha.js

I wrote a Node/Typescript app that used data from Firebase Cloud Firestore. The app worked perfectly and I was able to test my endpoints fine using simple mocha commands of the generated .js file. Here is an example of one of the test scripts:

```
import * as supertest from 'supertest'
import app from '../App'

describe('Risk API', () => {
  it('works to get /', () =>
    supertest(app)
      .get('/risks')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200)
  )
  it('does not allow put at top level', () =>
    supertest(app)
      .put('/risks')
      .expect(403)
  )
})
```

Here is the App.js that is referring to (imports and declarations excluded):

```
let riskRouter = require('./routes/Risk')

class App {
  public express

  constructor () {
    this.express = express()
    this.mountRoutes()
  }

  private mountRoutes (): void {
    const router = express.Router()

    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.json({
        message: 'Hello World!'
      })
    })
    this.express.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.express.use(cors({ origin: true }))
    this.express.use('/', router)
    this.express.use('/risks', functions.https.onRequest(riskRouter))
  }
}

export default new App().express
```

Here is the Risk router with only the GET endpoint:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const riskRouter = express.Router();
import { firestore, firebasestore } from '../firebase/firebase';


riskRouter.use(bodyParser.json());

riskRouter.route('/')
.get((req,res,next) => {
    return firestore.collection('risks').get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        let risks = [];
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const data = doc.data()
            const _id = doc.id
            risks.push({_id, ...data });
        });
        res.send(risks)
    })
    .catch( err => res.json({error: err}))
})

// POST, PUT and DELETE are implemented here but not needed for this discussion

module.exports = riskRouter
```

When I tried to migrate this to Firebase, I basically copied the entire node application to the /functions directory and made the following change to the App.ts file

```
let riskRouter = require('./routes/Risk')

class App {
  public express

  constructor () {
    this.express = express()
    this.mountRoutes()
  }

  private mountRoutes (): void {
    const router = express.Router()

    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.json({
        message: 'Hello World!'
      })
    })
    this.express.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.express.use(cors({ origin: true }))
    this.express.use('/', router)
    this.express.use('/risks', functions.https.onRequest(riskRouter))
  }
}

export default new App().express
```

In both cases, the test command in package.json is
"test": "tsc && mocha lib/**/*.spec.js"

Also, the Risk router is identical in both cases.

In the case that works, all the test simply run cleanly. Also, they are making calls to the external Firebase backend

In the case that fails, I get the following output:
Risk API
    1) works to get /

0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

1) Risk API works to get /:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
      at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
      at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)

All of my endpoints use some form of res.send(), res.json(), etc which I read is sufficient and the explicit use of done() is not needed. If I'm wrong about that, I'd like to know as well as the proper syntax to fix it.

I also tried running mocha directly on the generated test script using the --timeout 15000 option, but got the same result.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say: `I was able to test my endpoints fine` are you sure? Maybe you were just defining the test cases and thought the test run successfully?

Comment: I am not clear how is res.json() or res.data() are related to your test cases. Your endpoints might use them and they don't need the done call, but how is that connected to your mocha testing? which is a different code execution and its async, so it needs "done" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```js
import * as supertest from 'supertest'
import app from '../App'

describe('Risk API', (done) => {
  it('works to get /', () =>
    supertest(app)
      .get('/risks')
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect(200, done)
  )
  it('does not allow put at top level', (done) =>
    supertest(app)
      .put('/risks')
      .expect(403, done)
  )
})
```